# bash/shell read LINE more than once

Tags: bash, shell, stdin

I have a #!/bin/sh script where I need to read piped input more than once.

The way I'm iterating over it seems to discard it, for example the following;

```
while read LINE; do
  echo "-- $LINE"
done

while read LINE; do
  echo "## $LINE"
done
```

when called with

```
find ~/Desktop | ./my.sh
```

produces

```
-- /Users/me/Desktop/some.txt
-- /Users/me/Desktop/other.txt
```

and not

```
-- /Users/me/Desktop/some.txt
-- /Users/me/Desktop/other.txt
## /Users/me/Desktop/some.txt
## /Users/me/Desktop/other.txt
```

Is there a way I can preserve this input if I need to use it more than once?

Thanks.

Comment: Longer answer: yes. See bellow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to save the input yourself.

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0;
while read LINE; do
  LINES[$i]="${LINE}"
  i=$((i+1))
done

for ENTRY in "${LINES[@]}"; do
  echo "-- ${ENTRY}"
done


for ENTRY in "${LINES[@]}"; do
  echo "## ${ENTRY}"
done
```

Sample output:

```
ls /bin/b*|./test.sh
-- /bin/basename
-- /bin/bash
## /bin/basename
## /bin/bash
```

Comment: at least `LINES[$i]="$LINE"` ?

Answer (score 3):

One of many solution

```
TMP="/tmp/myfile.$$"
trap "rm -f '$TMP';exit" 0 2 15

while read LINE; do
  echo "-- $LINE"
done < <(tee $TMP)

exec < $TMP
while read LINE; do
  echo "## $LINE"
done
```

another one

```
TMP="/tmp/myfile.$$"
trap "rm -f '$TMP';exit" 0 2 15

cat - > $TMP

while read LINE; do
  echo "-- $LINE"
done < $TMP

while read LINE; do
  echo "## $LINE"
done < $TMP
```

Comment: +1 I would simply redirect input to the `while` loop, though, rather than redirect input for the entire shell: `while read LINE; do ...; done < $TMP`.

Comment: @chepner added one more example, thanx. ;)

Answer (score 2):

`cat` the input to a temporary file (`mktemp`). Then read the file as many times as needed.